# Multiple forms on one MVC form, model data does not pass to Action

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am creating a loop of objects/forms that will enable a user to update data for each object in a partial view. The unique data properly displays in the loop of forms but when I try to submit to the action, the model data that passes to the action is blank and doesn't pull the data from the form I'm submitting from.

In debugging, object data is successfully passed to each var item in the loop.

> @foreach (var item in ViewData["CtaList"] as
>   IEnumerable)

Ex. There are 5 individual forms that are created by the loop each with their own Save and Delete button. If I click Save on the 3rd form in the loop, it goes to the action but the MedInfoModel model for that individual object is blank.

**View**

```cs
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    ViewData["hidePluginCSS"] = "yes";
    @model POR.Common.MedInfoModel;
}
@foreach (var item in ViewData["CtaList"] as IEnumerable<POR.Common.CtaListModel>)
{
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Edit CTA</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="partialPlaceHolder">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCtaInfo/" + item.CtaId, "Med", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = item.CtaId, @class = "content-form form-horizontal" }))
            {
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="content-form form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group justify-content-end">
                            <label for="inputEmail" autocomplete="false" class="col-md-9 control-label">Select Type</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.CtaType, Model.CTATypeDropdown, new { @class = "form-control"})

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group justify-content-end">
                            <label for="inputEmail" autocomplete="false" class="col-md-9 control-label">Select Priority</label>

                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.CtaOrder, Model.CTAOrderDropdown, new { @class = "form-control" })

                        </div>

                        <div class="row mt-2">
                            <div class="col-md-12 r">
                                <button class="btn btn-raised btn-danger r" name="ctaSave" value="ctaDelete">Delete</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-raised btn-success r" name="ctaSave" value="ctaSave">Save</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            }


        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller:**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveCtaInfo(MedInfoModel model, int id)
        {

            string _sSubmit = Request.Form["ctaSave"].ToString();

            if (_sSubmit == "ctaSave")
            {
                // Code for cta save
                model.CtaActionType = "UPDATE";
                Helper.SQLSPCrudModel(ConnectionString, "storedProcedure", model);
            }
            else if (_sSubmit == "ctaDelete")
            {
                // code for cta delete
                model.CtaActionType = "DELETE";
                Helper.SQLSPCrudModel(ConnectionString, "storedProcedure", model);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Edit/" + id);

}
```

**Rendered Form HTML:**

```cs
<form action="/Med/SaveCtaInfo%2F1000" class="content-form form-horizontal" id="1000" method="post">                <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="form-group justify-content-end">
                            <label for="inputEmail" autocomplete="false" class="col-md-9 control-label">Select Type</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="item_0__CtaType" name="item[0].CtaType"><option value="PDF">PDF</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Call">Call</option>
<option value="Menu">Menu</option>
<option value="Video">Video</option>
</select>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group justify-content-end">
                            <label for="inputEmail" autocomplete="false" class="col-md-9 control-label">Select Priority</label>

                            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The CtaOrder field is required." id="item_0__CtaOrder" name="item[0].CtaOrder"><option value="0">0</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
</select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mt-2">
                            <div class="col-md-12 r">
                                <button class="btn btn-raised btn-danger r" name="ctaSave" value="ctaDelete">Delete</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-raised btn-success r" name="ctaSave" value="ctaSave">Save<div class="ripple-container"></div></button>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                </div></form>
```

**EDIT:**

I just noticed however that the form data is passing through via chrome dev tools as:

```
  item[0].CtaType: Call
  item[0].CtaOrder: 1
  item[0].CtaLink:
```

Where in a succesfull passing of the model in another action is passing through as:

```
 CtaType: Call
 CtaOrder: 1
 CtaLink:
```

Does the action need to be set up differently since it is no longer the parent model of the page?

Comment: How is your form being submitted? I don't see a submit button or js to handle it.

Comment: The buttons at the bottom of the view code. I tried using an input type of submit, but that didn't work either.

Comment: How are you confirming the model payload is empty? If you place a brake point here  `string _sSubmit = Request.Form["ctaSave"].ToString();`, is it being hit?

Comment: Yes. And when I hover over the model at said break point, click the down arrow to view the model properties, the data is empty/null. The id however is being populated in the action parameters.

Comment: hmmm odd, if you look at the forms data in your browser tools (f12) after the submit, does it contain anything?

Comment: The form data is showing in the dev tools of chrome

Comment: See Edit in Original Post

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to simply replace the following in the controller in original code I posted:

```cs
public ActionResult SaveCtaInfo(MedInfoModel model, int id)
```

with

```cs
public ActionResult SaveCtaInfo(MedInfoModel item, int id)
```

Thanks for your help  mxmissile. Sorry for wasting your time.